# What was the serpent’s plan?

Tags: rashi, parashat-bereishit, adam, eve-chava, satan

According to Rashi, the serpent desired Eve and his plan was that Adam eat from the tree and die so that he can have her [Rashi Genesis 3:1, Bereishis Rabbah 18:6]. If that was his plan, why would he cause her to eat from the tree first? Obviously, if he thought Adam would die from eating, Eve would too.

Comment: I’ve actually heard that his plan was to be with Adam, so he wanted Eve to die by eating from the tree and then he could be with adam

Comment: @CuriousYid I heard that from R Tovia Singer. It was jealous that Adam didn't find a mate among the animals, given that it could talk. Would love to find a source for that.

Comment: @RabbiKaii There are sources showing that the animals talked. And we have a verse from scripture showing Adam was naming the animals and there was a possibility he would choose a mate from them. Not enough sources for you?

Comment: @RabbiKaii heard that in his shiur too lol

Comment: @Aaron indeed it really doesn't take a big leap to read that jealousy between the lines

Comment: Whether the snake could talk is discussed by the Ramban, Ibn Ezra and others. There is a Medrash that the snake spoke Lashon Hakodesh. I've seen asked, that since according to Unkelos Gen. 2-7 speech is the result of the combination between body and "Nishmas Chaim", how could a serpent, without that, speak? It is more likely that Chava understood the language of animals

Comment: @RabbiKaii The source for Adam seeking a mate from the animal first but wasn't satisfied until he found Chava is in Yevamos 63a

Comment: Interesting @CuriousYid - the gemara in Sotah 9b says outright the snake desired Chava

Comment: @Dov אלו ואלו…?

Comment: Rashi and the midrash say : ניתאוה לה. Indicating that he wanted Eve

Comment: To me the story makes more sense that the snake wanted Adam.

Comment: @Aaron Perhaps, like me, it sounds more natural because we think of the snake as a man and it sounds wrong to have him want Adam given our standards. But imagine it like this- Adam is all alone in the garden and can’t find a mate, but the snake who is also intelligent and can also speak wants to be his mate and rule the world with Adam, but then some random woman comes along and steals his spot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [מהר"ל (גור אריה ג-טו)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gur_Aryeh_on_Bereishit.3.15.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) asks your question and he suggests that the snake thought that Chava, as a good wife, would offer the fruit to her husband first. The serpent expected him to die straight away, after which she would refrain from eating!
כי עשית זאת - ...ואם תאמר אחר שנתכוון לישא את חוה, הרי אם תאכל תמות? ויש לומר שחשב שדרך נשים לכבד בעליהן, ותתן לו קודם ולא תמות, כי תראה מיתת בעלה מיד ולא תאכל עוד.

Comment: This is amazing. The Torah is so vast in knowledge